# How to find repeated characters using regex in visual-studio?

Tags: regex, visual-studio

Example

`'abcdeeeeefghi'`  the repeating `'[eeeee]'` should match

`'abbdefgiijklmmn'`   the repeating `'[bb]'`, `'[ii]'` and `'[mm]'` should match

`'abcedefegehe'`   no match in this case

Comment: Change it to: `"(\p{L})\1*"`. You need to use quantifiers, to matc more than 2 length repetition. And you don't need look-ahead, as it will only return the first character. To return complete sequence, just remove look-ahead.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: @RohitJain not `(\p{L})\1*` but `(\p{L})\1+` as `*` needs nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), use the following regex:

```
{:c}\1+
```

(curly braces are used in VS2010 for capturing groups instead of the standard parentheses, and `:c` signifies an alphabetic character).

Comment: Thank you Tim, that was fast.

Answer (score 1):

```
{:c}\1+
```

You must use `+`, not `*` as `*` will match zero or more, thus `{:c}\1*` would match a single occurrence.

`:c` is used to specify the character class so you don't match repeated whitespace or punctuation.

Comment: This is not supported in VS 2010.

Comment: Still not correct. VS doesn't use parentheses for capturing groups.

Comment: Now this also matches and replaces `abcabc`.

Comment: haha i'll just upvote yours after i edit...apparently i have no clue with VS regexes...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think `(.)\1+` will do the job.

It matches a pattern with a character (any character) followed by itself occurring at least once. `\1` is for backreference to the first capture group (the character).

Comment: No, this is not the way VS has implemented regexes until version 2010.